# Scheduling n tasks on n machines with dependancies

Tags: scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs

So # of tasks = # of machines.

Given a DAG how would I approach this problem? I know how to do n jobs and 1 machine but I am stuck on this. Any hints/tips?